# can we schedule push notification using davibennun/laravel-push-notification

Tags: php, laravel, firebase, push-notification, scheduling

my question is can we schedule push notification using **davibennun/laravel-push-notification** or by using **firebase php sdk**, one solution is queues and cron jobs etc but i just want know that is it there any way we can just pass a paramenter **schedule_at** etc to notification config and our notification scheduled at that time,this is how i am sending push now

```
                $result = $push->setService('fcm')->setMessage([
                    'mutable_content' => true,
                    'notification' => [
                            'title'=> $title,
                            'body'=> $push_message,
                            'sound' => 'default',
                            "icon" => "new",
                            "content_available" => true,
                            'data' =>  $metadata,
                            'type' => 'basic'
                        ],
                        'data' => [
                            'title'=> $title,
                            'message'=> $push_message,
                            'sound' => 'default',
                            "icon" => "new",
                            'metadata' => $metadata,
                            'type' => 'basic',
                            'data' =>  $metadata,
                        ],
                    ])
                    ->setDevicesToken($users_devices_chunk)
                    ->send()
                    ->getFeedback();
```

Answer (score 1):

I think there is no approach to schedule notification by the Firebase but there is two way you can do it:

1. Send notifications as data and control the time of action by your clients.
2. Use the cronjob or [delayed dispatching](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/queues#delayed-dispatching).

The delayed dispatching adds delay time to the jobs before the process:

```
SendNotificationJob::dispatch($data)->delay(now()->addMinutes(10));
```

Comment: yes you are right, i searched alot but did'nt find any direct way to schedule notifications, so i decided to handel this with cron, thanks for your answer